# How to add a newline in xargs

Tags: xargs, newlines

I'm trying to write a command to capture every license in the linux OS (kali) and associate it with the correct package. The basic idea is that you search /usr/share/doc recursively for "copyright" file, then you cat that and search for "^License" the leading license. There can be multiple per package.

I'm trying to create a csv that takes all of the package names and puts them in the first field of each row, and then follows it with each license comma delimited.

My basic flow: make a list of every package (done). Make a list where each line is csv of the licenses found. Then just paste file 1 and file 2, boom.

Problem, I have to swap the newlines in the output of the command with comma's, but I need to then re-insert a newline at the end for each iteration of xargs so my csv licenses will line up with the package list.  I've tried this dozens of ways. When I do command substitution it breaks translate or echo (doesn't read `\n` as a newline anymore. I've tried `\\n`, no luck).

Here is what I have that just needs a way to put a newline per xargs cycle.

```
find . -name copyright |xargs -l cat |grep "^License" |tr '\n' ','
```

So if I could just pipe to something that inserts `\n` after every xarg cycle I'd be done. I know I can write a for loop for this with variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're okay with awk, try this solution:

```
find $PWD -name copyright | xargs awk 'BEGIN{ORS=","} FNR==1{print "\n"FILENAME}; $0 ~ /^License/ {print $0}' | sed 's/,$//g'  |awk -F',' 'NF>1'
```

Comment: That worked. Thank you so much. I'll read up on awk, looks like I need more tools in my tool box. Thanks again.

Comment: @bashCypher glad it worked.